# "BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range" on an UPDATE?

Tags: mysql

On my MySQL database, I have a unsigned mediumint column, which I keep incrementing and decrementing its value.

However, I want to be sure that it doesn't decrement when its value is 0. If I do, the UPDATE will make the value to take the maximum value of mediumint, 16777215.

So, I have this query when decrementing:

```
UPDATE `counters` SET `received`=IF(CAST(`received`-1 AS SIGNED)>0, `received`-1, 0) WHERE `id`="1234"
```

This was the only trick I got to work with only one query.

It works very well on MySQL 5.1, but, yesterday I upgraded to MySQL 5.5 and now I get these errors:

```
BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`db_main`.`counters`.`received` - 1)'
```

Is there any way to fix this?
Or... is there any other way to make sure, in only one query, that it won't take the value of "16777215" when subtracting 1 to 0?

**EDIT** - I could use the WHERE, adding " AND received > 0". The thing is that sometimes I want to update two columns at the same time, and if I put all the columns > 0 in the WHERE clause, it won't update ANY of the columns.

Thank you.

Comment: How about `min(x, x-1)`?

Comment: @Hurkyl - that function seems not working like that. min(col) is only for 1 column. But, theoretically, that would work. Maybe the name of the function is another? Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @Hurkyl - Oh, it's the LEAST(). "LEAST(received, received-1)", but it gives the same error of my question. That's sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems a little ... torturous, with all that casting and conditional stuff (as an aside, per-row functions rarely scale well in big tables).

Why don't you just modify the `where` clause to stop the decrment if it's already zero?

```
update counters set received = received - 1
    where id = '1234' and received > 0
```

---

If there are other columns you want updated irrespective of the value of `received`, you can do that with a transaction:

```
begin transaction
update counters set received = received - 1 where id = '1234' and received > 0
update counters set xyzzy = 'plugh' where id = '1234'
commit transaction
```

This will decrement `received`, but not below zero, and it will change `xyzzy` no matter what. And it still keeps away from the per-row stuff that brings down many queries.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first choice, yes. The thing is that sometimes I want to update two columns at the same time, and if I put all the columns > 0 in the WHERE clause, it won't update ANY of the columns. Thank you.

Comment: That would work, but I'd still like to try something that @ Hurkyl suggested in the comments on my question. Is there any "min(x, y)" similar function? I can't find on Google. If you know, you may want to complete your answer with a 3rd suggestion :) Thank you!

Comment: Oh, it's the LEAST(). "LEAST(received, received-1)", but it gives the same error of my question. That's sad.

Comment: @Nuno, no, I really wouldn't want to provide a third option :-) Whether that function exists or not, it's still going to be a performance killer for large tables, and I'm near-anal-retentive in my pursuit of database performance. We do DB work under DB2/z (mainframe) where ten million rows is considered a particularly small table.

Comment: I understand! So, the transaction is the best way to go, in your opinion? Thank you very much once again.